# How to order dynamics crm chart Legend in UCI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

We have a stacked chart and the Legend is shown in wrong order. In WebUI the order is correct. When we change the order of legend in XML the colors are in wrong order.

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this problem and has solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

We created microsoft ticket and the answer we got is that this is by design because UCI use .net Charts and this behaviour is according to Microsoft "by design" it only occur on Stacked horizontal charts